# Create mappings/macros with keydown?

Tags: key-bindings

Is it possible to create mappings or macros based on `keydown` and `keyup` events?

For example, if you press `i` you enter `insert` mode, and if you press `esc` you leave insert mode and enter `normal` mode.

Could you make it so that if you pressed down `i` you entered insert mode, and when you released it, you left insert mode?

(not that you would want to do that, I am just giving it as an example of behavior)

Comment: Something "similar" is possible either at OS level, or with special firmware in certain mechanical keyboards (I'm thinking at [Hasu's TMK](https://github.com/tmk/tmk_keyboard)). For example, you can then map Caps Lock to act as ESC if pressed and released alone, but to act as CTRL instead, if another key is pressed before Caps Lock release.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer is no.

Keys are registered as raw I/O; there's no concept of `keyup/down/press` like you'd find in `javascript`

Rather vim thinks of input in terms of its modes. You have quite a bit of flexibility when creating bindings for different modes.

> :nmap - Display normal mode maps
>
> :imap - Display insert mode maps
>
> :vmap - Display visual and select mode maps
>
> :smap - Display select mode maps
>
> :xmap - Display visual mode maps
>
> :cmap - Display command-line mode maps
>
> :omap - Display operator pending mode maps

**note:** In neovim and newer versions of Vim, there is an additional mode; terminal mode, which has its own set of mappings