# Mapping tab with another key

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

Can I map the Tab key as the same style as Control plus another key? For example ,`<c-k>` means press the **Control** and **k** keys together. I've tried `<tab-k>` but it didn't work.

Comment: It's worth noting that the only keys that can be used as modifiers (i.e. the first part of a multi-key mapping) are Alt, Ctrl, and Shift.

Comment: Also worth a mention that (at least in a terminal), <Tab> is a control sequence; it is the same as <C-i>... It effectively already has a modifier on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming you mean "tab" not "tap"...*

---

#### No.

This is not possible *purely* in vim. You are basically asking vim to recognize <kbd>Tab</kbd> as a [modifier key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key). The only keys that vim recognize as a modifier key are <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Meta</kbd>, and, on Mac, <kbd>Command</kbd>. (See `:help keycodes`.)

And since vim cannot recognize [keyup/keydown events](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7005/2920), you cannot use vimscript to handle tab presses and pretend it's a modifier key.

The only way you could achieve this would be by hacking your keyboard's firmware/drivers and making the tab button work differently, which is beyond my knowledge and way beyond the scope of a vim question. I don't know if you could bind it as a custom modifier or if you'd have to remap it to one of the existing modifier keys.